# String format using java

Tags: java

I have to make below statement as string.i am trying,but it's giving invalid character sequence.I know it is basic,But not able to do this.any help on this appreciated.

```
String str="_1";

'\str%' ESCAPE '\'

Output should be: '\_1%' ESCAPE '\'.
```

Thanks,

Chaitu

Comment: You've only shown one actual line of code. Please post a short but complete example instead. My guess is that you're looking for string interpolation in a way which really isn't supported in Java, but it's hard to tell for sure...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String result = "'\\" + str + "%' ESCAPE '\\'";
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside a string, a backslash character will "escape" the character after it - which causes that character to be treated differently.

Since `\` has this special meaning, if you actually want the `\` character itself in the string, you need to put `\\`. The first backslash escapes the second, causing it to be treated as a literal `\` inside the string.

Knowing this, you should be able to construct the resulting string you need. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
String str="_1";
String source = "'\\str%' ESCAPE '\\'";
String result = source.replaceAll("str", str);
```

Another way to implement string interpolation. The `replaceAll` function finds all occurrences of `str` in the source string and replaces them by the passed argument.

To encode the backslash `\` in a Java string, you have to duplicate it, because a single backslash works as an escape character.

Beware that the first argument if `replaceAll` is actually a [regular expression](http://www.regular-expressions.info), so some characters have a special meaning, but for simple words it will work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

```
String str="_1";
String output = String.format("'\\%s%%' ESCAPE '\\'",str);
System.out.println(output);//prints '\_1%' ESCAPE '\'
```